# Angular 2.4 app won't start

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I was having issues with my app not starting in the newest version of Angular 2 and haven't found any solutions on Stackoverflow, so I figured I'd ask the question and answer it myself. My app was stuck on the loading page and there were no errors in the browser console, so it was very difficult to debug.

Comment: Despite the fact that you've asked this with the intension of self answering, I think an MVCE would still be helpful to picture the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the issue is with child routing, which is why the newest quickstart runs just fine... it doesn't use child routing. If your app uses child routing and suddenly won't start even though you have no errors in your browser console, it is likely because you have upgraded to version 3.4.8 for @angular/router. This version has bugs and should not be used yet. The solution (until Angular 2 fixes the bug(s)) is to update your router version in package.json file to the following:

`"@angular/router": "3.4.7",`